# Is it possible for EF6 migration up command to delete database with these commands?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

Somehow either, my C# code, or entity framework 6 is dropping and creating a database when  I run

```
PM> update-database -verbose
```

from an explicit migration with an up() method that looks like this...

```
public override void Up()
{
    AddColumn("dbo.Term", "Term_Id", c => c.Int());
    CreateIndex("dbo.Term", "Term_Id");
    AddForeignKey("dbo.Term", "Term_Id", "dbo.Term", "Id");
}
```

-verbose generates this...

```
Origin: Configuration).
Applying explicit migrations: [201410271927053_addTermsTable2].
Applying explicit migration: 201410271927053_addTermsTable2.
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Term] ADD [Term_Id] [int]
CREATE INDEX [IX_Term_Id] ON [dbo].[Term]([Term_Id])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Term] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Term_dbo.Term_Term_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Term_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Term] ([Id])
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
```

(plus the migration insert statement)

None of which indicates (to me) the db is about to be dropped.

Can someone confirm this does not drop?

Does it matter that

```
this is an Azure SQL database?
that the columns were added in response to adding this.. to the class?
public virtual ICollection<Term> urls { get; set; }
```

Any pointers on how to make sure I know when a drop create is going to occur?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you setting a [Database Initializer](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)?

Comment: Your initializer seems to be the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` rather than `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`.

Comment: I am using DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges, researching about how to change to MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion unable to just swap terms. need to add ,Configuration()